# listview OnItemClick listener not work in fragment

Tags: android, xml, listview, android-fragments

I used listview in fragment but I used list `onItemClick` listener not working. My code below and how to perfect solution.

```
 public class StoreProfileFragment extends Fragment{
        ListView lv;
        ArrayList<MyStore_list_dto> list = new ArrayList<MyStore_list_dto>();
        MyApplication app;
        MyListAdapter adtstore;
        View rootView;
        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_store_profile, container, false);
            app = (MyApplication) getActivity().getApplicationContext();

            list = DBAdpter.getMyStoreData(app.getUserID());
            lv = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.myStore_listview);

    adtstore = new MyListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        lv.setAdapter(adtstore);
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
                    long id) {
                Log.v("log_tag", "List Item Click");
            }
        });


            return rootView;
        }
        public class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
            private LayoutInflater mInflater;

            public MyListAdapter(Context context) {
                mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            }

            public int getCount() {
                return list.size();
            }

            public Object getItem(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public long getItemId(int position) {
                return position;
            }

            public View getView(final int position, View convertView,
                    ViewGroup parent) {
                convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.custome_mystorelist,
                        null);
                ImageButton store_Name_img = (ImageButton) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.my_Store_logo_image);

                TextView store_Name_txt = (TextView) convertView
                        .findViewById(R.id.mystore_list_name);


                store_Name_txt.setText( list.get(position).name);



                if (list.get(position).image != null) {
                    byte[] Image_getByte;
                    try {
                        Image_getByte = Base64.decode(list.get(position).image);
                        ByteArrayInputStream bytes = new ByteArrayInputStream(
                                Image_getByte);
                        BitmapDrawable bmd = new BitmapDrawable(bytes);
                        Bitmap bm = bmd.getBitmap();
                        store_Name_img.setImageBitmap(bm);

                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                store_Name_img.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
                        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fm
                                .beginTransaction();
                        MyStoreItemFragment fm2 = new MyStoreItemFragment();
                        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.rela_myStore_fragment,
                                fm2, "HELLO");
                        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
                        fragmentTransaction.commit();
                        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                        bundle.putString("position", list.get(position).store_id);
                        fm2.setArguments(bundle);

                    }
                });

                return convertView;
            }
        }
    }
```

ListView in xml file below:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/myStore_listview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:dividerHeight="0dip"
     >
</ListView>
```

Custome listItem xml below:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/rela_store_fragment"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dip"
    android:background="@android:color/white" >


        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/my_Store_logo_image"
            android:layout_width="60dip"
            android:layout_height="60dip"
             android:layout_margin="5dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mystore_list_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/my_Store_logo_image"
            android:layout_marginBottom="18dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="18dp"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/my_Store_logo_image"
             android:layout_margin="5dip"
            android:text="dfdsfds"
            android:textColor="#040404"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:typeface="sans"  />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5551042/onitemclicklistener-not-working-in-listview-android or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2098558/listview-with-clickable-editable-widget

Answer (score 17):

Add this

```
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"
```

to the RelativeLayout  in `listItem.xml`.

I guess `ImageButton` takes focus when you click on list row.

Edit:

Consider using a `ViewHolder` pattern

Reference:

http://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/smooth-scrolling.html

Comment: @crickpatel0024 what happens when you click on list row. Does imagebutton take focus. check that

Comment: @crickpatel0024 glad to help. One more suggestion use a `ViewHolder` helps improve performance

Comment: I've spent about 6 hours to solve ListView OnItemClick in fragment problem (API19). Moved rootview.findViewById... in Fragment.onCreateView(); Moved adapter's here; Changed layout types in fragment, listview and listview's item...; Logged and debugged everything: fragmentActivity, RootView, container, listview, convertedView etc...

So, in the ListView's item layout absolutely must have:
1) android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants";
2) android:clickable="false" - or even better to remove android:clickable from ListView Item.

Thank you so much!

Comment: Best answer ever.

Answer (score 2):

Add these properties in your custom xml file

```
 android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
 android:focusable="false"
```

for your TextView and ImageButton.

Answer (score 0):

whenever you list item contains something like button then this type of problem comes.
you should use a view holder in you adapter class.

```
 private class ViewHolder{
           ImageButton imagebutton;
           TextView textView;        

         }
```

use it in your getview method. hope this will work for you.

Comment: ViewHolder certainly helps in improving performance. But what has that gotta do with item clikc listener?

Comment: @Raghunandan what you said is very correct, but when a list item contains element like button check box it just prevent selection of an itemview item. for details see [this](http://cyrilmottier.com/2011/11/23/listview-tips-tricks-4-add-several-clickable-areas/). very well explained.

Comment: read the post in full to understand the blog you just linked especially **Why, the hell, are my itemviews no longer clickable?**.

Answer (score 0):

**Here you go:** Use onActivityCreated() instead and use the code here:

```
@Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListView lv1 = (ListView)getActivity().findViewById(R.id.myStore_listview);
        adtstore = new MyListAdapter(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        lv.setAdapter(adtstore);
        lv1.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,
                    long arg3) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Item clicked : " + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

        });

    }
```

Should work now.. :)