# Listview onItemClickListener inside a Fragment

Tags: listview, android-fragments, onitemclicklistener

So I got my Fragment here with a Listview inside, which is working pretty nice.

But I can't figure out how to use the onItemClickListener inside a Fragment.

I could need some help putting it inside the Fragmentcode.

I found this [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14899904/solved-onitemclicklistener-on-a-listview-inside-a-fragment-not-working) already, but I still can't get it to work

**FragmentJanuar.java**

```js
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


public class FragmentJanuar extends Fragment {

    private ArrayList<meetings> myMeetings = new ArrayList<meetings>();
    private ContactsAdapter adapter;
    private ListView lv;


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){

        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_januar, container, false);
        myMeetings.add(new meetings("Event 1", "01.01.2001", "01:00", "1€", "Ort 1", "Strasse 1", 0, "www.event1url.de", "http://www.maplinkevent1.com"));
        myMeetings.add(new meetings("Event 2", "01.01.2001", "01:00", "1€", "Ort 1", "Strasse 1", 0, "www.event1url.de", "http://www.maplinkevent1.com"));

        lv =(ListView)v.findViewById(R.id.listview_januar);

        adapter = new ContactsAdapter(getActivity(), myMeetings);

        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        return v;
    }


    private class ContactsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

        private FragmentActivity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater;
        private ArrayList<meetings> data;

        public ContactsAdapter (FragmentActivity a, ArrayList<meetings> d){
            activity = a;
            data = d;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return data.size();
        }

        @Override
        public meetings getItem(int position) {
            return data.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View v = convertView;
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_view, null);


            meetings currentMeeting = myMeetings.get(position);

            //Eventname
            TextView Event = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_txtEvent);
            Event.setText(currentMeeting.getEventname());

            //date
            TextView Date = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_txtDate);
            Date.setText(currentMeeting.getDate());

            //Time
            TextView Time = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_txtTime);
            Time.setText("Uhrzeit: " + currentMeeting.getTime() + "Uhr" );

            //Price
            TextView Price = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_txtPrice);
            Price.setText("Eintritt: "+ currentMeeting.getPrice());

            //LocationOrt
            TextView LocationOrt = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_txtLocationOrt);
            LocationOrt.setText("Location: " + currentMeeting.getLocationOrt());

            //LocationStrasse
            TextView LocationStrasse = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_txtLocationStrasse);
            LocationStrasse.setText(currentMeeting.getLocationStrasse());

            //EventUrl
            TextView Eventurl = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.item_txtEventurl);
            Eventurl.setText("Url: " + currentMeeting.getEventurl());

            return v;
        }
    }

}
```

Here's the onItemClickListener that I want to insert.

```js
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                String myurl = myMeetings.get(position).getMapslink().toString();
                Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                i.setData(Uri.parse(myurl));
                startActivity(i);
                return;
            }
        });
```

Comment: you want click listener on the list items ??

Comment: Yes, that's what I want.

Answer (score 0):

```
R.layout.item_view
```

give id to the root view i.e. view in the top hierachy the view of the above layout then

```
public View getView
```

then register a click listener in the above method

for eg. `rootView.setOnCLickListenere(this)`

over-ride the `onClick()` with 
    activity.startActivity("xyz."abc")