# Android Async task JSON Parsing onItemClickListener not working

Tags: android, listview, android-asynctask

I am creating a fragment inside an Activity where I am trying to parse a JSON string fetched from internet using AsyncTask and display the JSON parsed data in a list view. 
The items display in the list properly.
But when I click on the item on the list, click listener doesn't fire. 
What am I missing here.

My Activity File is show below:

```
    @SuppressWarnings("DefaultFileTemplate")
    public class LaundryFragment extends BaseFragment {

        private final String TAG = LaundryFragment.class.getSimpleName();
        private ProgressDialog pDialog;
        private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> laundryList;
        private ListView lv ;

        @Override
        public void onStart() {
            super.onStart();
            sendView(LaundryTestActivity.class.getSimpleName(), null); //sending to Google Analytics
        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            return inflater.inflate(R.layout.laundry_alerts, container, false);
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
            laundryList = new ArrayList<>();

            new GetLaundry().execute();
            lv = (ListView) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.laundry_list); //working

            lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    Log.d("laundry",view.toString());
                    Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Log.d("laundry","log message");
                }
            });
        }


        /**
         * Async task class to get json by making HTTP call
         */
        private class GetLaundry extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> > {


            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute() {
                super.onPreExecute();
                // Showing progress dialog
                pDialog = new ProgressDialog(getActivity());
                pDialog.setMessage("Please wait...");
                pDialog.setCancelable(true);
                pDialog.show();
            }

            @Override
            protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
                HttpHandler sh = new HttpHandler();

                // Making a request to url and getting response
                String url = "https://www.laundryalert.com/cgi-bin/backoffice/MachineState.py?loc=redwolves&room=All&format=JSON";
                String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url);

                Log.e(TAG, "Response from url: " + jsonStr);

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                        // Getting JSON Array node
                        JSONObject location = jsonObj.getJSONObject("location");
                        //Array of rooms like STEM Den, Honors 3,...
                        JSONArray rooms = location.getJSONArray("rooms");

                        // looping through All rooms
                        for (int i = 0; i < rooms.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject r = rooms.getJSONObject(i);

                            String roomName = r.getString("name");
                            int washerCount = 0;
                            int availableWasherCount = 0;
                            int dryerCount = 0;
                            int availableDryerCount = 0;
                            JSONObject c = rooms.getJSONObject(i);

                            JSONArray machines = c.getJSONArray("machines");
                            HashMap<String, String> laun =  new HashMap<>();
                            for (int j = 0; j < machines.length() ; j++ ){
                                JSONObject machine = machines.getJSONObject(j);
                                if(machine.getString("description").contains("Washer")) {
                                    washerCount++;
                                    if(machine.getString("status").contains("Available")){
                                        availableWasherCount++;
                                    }
                                }
                                else {
                                    dryerCount++;
                                    if(machine.getString("status").contains("Available")){
                                        availableDryerCount++;
                                    }
                                }
                            }

                            laun.put("name",roomName);
                            laun.put("AvailWasher",Integer.toString(availableWasherCount));
                            laun.put("AvailDryer",Integer.toString(availableDryerCount));
                            laun.put("TotalWasher",Integer.toString(washerCount));
                            laun.put("TotalDryer", Integer.toString(dryerCount));
                            laundryList.add(laun);


                        }
                    } catch (final JSONException e) {

                        Log.e(TAG, "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage());
                        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                        "Json parsing error: " + e.getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Couldn't get json from server.");
                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(),
                                    "Couldn't get json from server. Check LogCat for possible errors!",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show();
                        }
                    });
                }
                return laundryList;
            }

            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>  result) {
                super.onPostExecute(result);
                // Dismiss the progress dialog
                if (pDialog.isShowing())
                    pDialog.dismiss();

                ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        getActivity(), result,
                        R.layout.laundry_detail, new String[]{"name", "AvailWasher", "TotalWasher", "AvailDryer",
                        "TotalDryer"}, new int[]{R.id.tvResidenceName, R.id.availWasher, R.id.totalwasher,
                        R.id.availDryer, R.id.totalDryer});

                lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"hello from post execute",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        }
   }
```

laundry_detail.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:padding="@dimen/news_item_padding" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="@dimen/news_item_padding"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResidenceName"
            android:text="Residence Name"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:textColor="@color/ASTATE_DARK_GRAY"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Available Washers"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/availWasher"
                    android:text="2"
                    android:layout_gravity="right"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Total Washers"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalwasher"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="2dp"
                android:background="#DCDCDC"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Available Dryers"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/availDryer"
                    android:text="0"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>


            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

                <TextView
                    android:text="Total Dryers"
                    android:layout_weight="3"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/totalDryer"
                    android:text="10"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: Please provide the laundry_detail layout content

Comment: Probably your layout is getting the focus. Try using `android:focusable="false"` to each focusable view in your layout

Comment: @GVillani82 I have laundry_detail.xml and laundry_alerts.xml. In which layout shall I add android:focusable="false".

Comment: @AhmedHegazy I added the file. Can you try to help?

Comment: Try applying it to the root, adding also `focusableInTouchMode="false"`

Comment: @GVillani82 http://pastebin.com/c54VzXh7 and http://pastebin.com/6vRVAAr8 are the two xml files. Please see if it is what you want it to be. I am still not getting result.

Comment: Can you put the onitem click listener in the activity and check? I'm not at a computer so can't run the code and check

Comment: @DheerajBhaskar How do I add click listener in the activity?

Comment: @AasthaDahal Your basefragment will get added in an activity, in that class. Forget that, you should do a line by line debug and see why this is not working. Can you upload your project (to Google drive or something)  and give a link so that I can check?

Comment: @DheerajBhaskar I wish I could, but its my university app, I am not allowed to upload the whole project. I can upload some activity and layouts if it helps.